# background-image not showing up in Django

Tags: css, django

I have an `accounts` app, and I have an icon in `accounts/static/accounts/images/mail-icon.png` that I want to use as a background-image in my CSS, and in my template I have:

```
<a id="mail-icon" href="{% url 'register' %}">Registration via Email address</a>
```

In my `register.css` (which is located in `accounts/static/accounts/css/register.css` I have:

```
#mail-icon {
    background-image: url(../images/mail-icon.png);
}
```

When I check Network tab of my developer tools, I see that I'm getting a 200 or 304, however the image is not appearing for some reason. I have tried to restart the server but had no success.

The image is appearing if I use:

```
<img src="{% static 'accounts/images/mail-icon.png' %}">
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Because of the css style of the element. You could make it visible by change display property of #mail-icon, or change width and height, give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
#mail-icon{
        background-image: url('/static/img/mail-icon.png');
        background-size: 100% auto;
        height: 100px; 
        width: 100px;
      }
```

```html
<a id="mail-icon" href="{% url 'register' %}">Registration via Email address</a>
  <img src="{% static "accounts/img/mail-icon.png" %}" alt="mail-icon">
```